# My car won't start no dashlights no sound no start seat ibiza fr 2014

Tags: starting, seat-ibiza

I changed the airbag kit on the car and it started a couple of times then it kept on turning off, now it won't start at all and theres no dashlights, all the relays are good and checked the fuses too non of them is broken, I can hear the fuel pump when I turn the key and tried to jump start the car too I don't know what else to check or if I'm missing any fuses that I have not seen yet, forgot to mention my central locking system stopped working too.
Help

Comment: Which electrical items on the car still work?

Comment: What was the reason you replaced your airbag?  Were you in an accident?

Comment: Yh the front bumper was gone  and the airbags no electrical things work on the car the key gets the little red light when  I press it but nothing happens

Comment: I suspect the issue with your central locking/security system may be preventing your car from staying running.  I would have this checked out first to resolve the issue and eliminate it as a possible cause.  A mobile locksmith experienced with car security systems should be able to diagnose and resolve the locking/security system issue.